# Angular2: *ngFor does not update when array is updated

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have an array of objects (`arr`). In one of my component's inputs, in the `(change)` method, I modify the attribute of one of the objects but in the view (`*ngFor`) nothing changes. I read that Angular’s change detection doesn't check the contents of arrays or objects, so I’ve tried these:

```
this.arr = this.arr.slice();

this.arr = [...this.arr];
```

But the view doesn't change, it still shows the old attribute. In the `(change)` method with `console.log()` I got the correct array. Weird, but this one works: `this.arr = [];`
(I’ve tried `NgZone` and `markForCheck()` too.)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You could also use the `trackBy` option in your `*ngFor` expression, providing a unique ID for every item inside the array. This does make you 100% responsible for change detection, so update this (unique) property every time the item in the array changes. Angular will then only re-render the list if any item inside your array has been given a different `trackBy` property:

```
*ngFor="let item of (itemList$ | async); trackBy: trackItem"
```

or:

```
*ngFor="let item of itemList; trackBy: trackItem"
```

where:

`trackItem` is a public method in your component:

```js
public trackItem (index: number, item: Item) {
  return item.trackId;
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Answer (score 38):

Since you mentioned that you already tried `markForCheck()`, you should try detectChanges instead (that just what worked for me and markForCheck did not work). For those that need the steps:

Add ChangeDetectorRef to your imports:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';
```

Add ChangeDetectorRef to your constructor:

```
constructor(
    private changeDetection: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) { }
```

Then on the next line after you update the array:

```
this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
```

Comment: if trackby dont detect the change in array, use this sample and enjoy it.

Comment: these lines of code just saved me! thank you

Comment: only code that worked.

Comment: It took me a while to find this answer, however, the only solution that worked and unlocked me was this method this.changeDetection.detectChanges(); . Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 7):

late to the game but creating a deep clone using lodash worked for me

`this.arr = cloneDeep(this.arr);`

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#cloneDeep

Comment: don't need lo-dash for this. `this.arr = this.arr.map(el => Object.assign({}, el)` or `this.arr =  [...this.arr]` it it's an array of primitives.

Answer (score 4):

1. Check if your component is configured with changeDetection:cHangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush, if you are going this then after updation of array you have to call changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()
2. You can also implement onChange lifecycle hook and change values of array inside this function.

Answer (score 4):

I solved this error by adding a changDetection directive on @component as follows

```
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-page',
      templateUrl: './page.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss'],
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.Default
    })
```

You also need to import it

```
import { Component, OnInit, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from '@angular/core';
```

There are two strategies onPush and Default

The onPush uses the CheckOnce strategy, meaning that automatic change detection is deactivated until reactivated by setting the strategy to Default (CheckAlways). Change detection can still be explictly invoked.

while the Default uses the CheckAlways strategy, in which change detection is automatic until explicitly deactivated.

Source [Docs](https://angular.io/api/core/ChangeDetectionStrategy)

Comment: Weird that you had to specify you wanted to use the *default* value. Is there any place in your configuration where you would define your changeDetectionStrategy as onPush by default ?

Comment: Yes, in some other components, while using angular with firestore, there some instances i had to specify onPush changeDetectionStrategy especially when using local arrays with data that was hardcoded onto a service file.

Answer (score 1):

I was able update the component using [ngZone](https://angular.io/guide/zone)

```
export class comp {
  arr: type[] = []
  
  constructor (
    private zone: NgZone
  ) {}

  updateArr(data: type) {
     this.arr.push(this.zone.run(() => data))
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a deep copy by doing

```
this.arr = Object.assign({}, NEW_VALUE);
```

Comment: It's not a deep copy, it's a shallow one. And this code works for objects, not for arrays, doesn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Incase anyone else runs into my situation, make sure that the component that is updating is the same copy as the one being rendered.

I was using `@ViewChild(MyComponent, { static: true }) private test: MyComponent` to pass data to the component with the ngfor. (In my case that ended up locking onto another copy I didn't know about)

I was able to fix it by adding the attribute `#mycomp` to my component tag in the html and changing the above to `@ViewChild('mycomp', { static: true }) private test: MyComponent`

Answer (score 0):

If you reassign an array the change detection won't notice the change. So instead of reassigning an array like `this.arr = ...` change the array directly. This could look like this:

```js
this.arr.splice(0); // empty the array, without reassigning it
this.arr.push(...); // push new items
```

That way you don't need to call the change detection manually.

#### Example

Let's say a have a list for a table which can be filtered (the user can i.e. search). So I will have a `list` which contains all possible items, and a `filteredList` which is used in the UI and shown to the user.

```js
// in ngOnInit I load the full list
this.list = this.myService.getList();
this.filteredList = [...this.list] // Since I will change the filtered list directly instead of reassigning it, I need to make a copy to not affect the original full list.

// then in a filter function, i.e. filterList()
this.filteredList.splice(0);
this.filteredList.push([...this.list.filter(/* ... */)]); // Again I need to push copies
```

Answer (score -2):

Any time I need to deal with *ngFor that needs change detection I prefer using behaviorSubject and async pipe.
(I know this is a longer solution. Using behavior subject makes it easy to work with change detection)

```
array$ = new BehaviorSubject([]);//Declare your array
```

When you need to update your array

```
array$.next(newArray)://Pass in new array data
```

if you want to read your array value in the .ts file use this

```
array$.getValue()
```

in your .HTML file

```
*ngFor='let obj of (array$ | async)'
```